can ii start the ubuntu desktop from a command line prompt, and if so, how?
I recently downloaded the 24-04 1 LTS upgrade and installed it. Now when I boot into Ubuntu I get a command line login prompt. I have tried the various fixes suggested regrading changing GRUB lines, etc, but nothing seems to make any difference -  I can't  get a GUI desktop to run. If I can't start a desktop then how do I fix this - can I reupgrade from the command line or anything?

I'm not sure what you meant by upgrade?  If you were using 24.04 LTS already; just applying security fixes & updates using apt upgrade would have applied the fixes & had you using 24.04.1; or in rare circumstances a apt full-upgrade if using some sources.. but that doesn't require re-install? or were you using 22.04?  Your details are unclear. Can you login to text terminal? are you getting a DM/greeter asking for long and it fails? (that can be something such as lack of space in $HOME or your user directory)..  Your details are unclear to me sorry

You can try startx. At least, that should give you some errors that prevent the GUI from starting.

sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target

Ok - i was running 22.04.1 and upgraded to 24.04.1, or at least tried to. When Ubuntu restarted I was presented with a tty1 connection prompting me for login details, which when supplied left me with the command line and no desktop. How can I get the desktop to run? Following the advice re reinstall gnome-desktop i was left with a raft of missng gets from the au.archive.ubuntu.com mirror. Seems to me reinstall and the australian archive may not be in sync - is there any way I can change to another mirror for this reinstall?

If you were running 22.04.1, the system would not have allowed you to release-upgrade as a 22.04.1 system would mean you've not applied security fixes since ~ Feb-2023 and you'd be told to apply all upgrades BEFORE you could perform release-upgrade (you'd upgrade to 22.04.5 before upgrade to 24.04.1 is possible). The aussie mirror (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/mirror.aarnet.edu.au-archive) was up to date on last check, and I doubt that's your issue... but the messages are required to be helpful.
